# 0X Swap failing when swapping Token X for Native Currency Smart Contract Integration

Tags: 0x, binance-smart-chain, soldity

i have a contract that i would like to utilize the zeroEx protocol with

i am calling the qoute endpoint like this

https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955&buyToken=0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&sellAmount=5000000000000000000&takerAddress=0xadA75b297dE5391E6e0F30a89fb6b3F816b4A5BE&slippagePercentage=0.01&skipValidation=true

this is the API qoute URL

i then call my contract with the bytes data returned from this endpoint

```
const I = await axios.get(url, {
  timeout: 10000,
  headers: optionsCreateZeroEx.headers

});

const swapDataI: any = I.data;

console.log(swapDataI)
```

I Then Utilize the response.data and call my contract method as part of the callData params to my contract method

once all tokens are transfered to my contract

```
 IERC20Upgradeable(sData.tokenFrom).safeTransferFrom(
                _msgSender(),
                address(this),
                sData.swappingTokenAmount
            );
```

I perfrom the following call

```
 (success, result) = 0xContract.call(sData.data);
```

where sData.data being the data returned from zeroEx endpoint

but no matter what i cannot get pass my require

```
require(success, "AGG Swap Fail");
```

Any Help Would be appreciated Thank You Team.

Answer (score 0):

I Have Resolved the issue One needs to make sure we have in your contract the following

```
    receive() external payable {}
```

very simple oversight on my behalf but hope this can help someone in the future